# I got a problem in running model function

Tags: class, model, regression, frame, forecast

when i run this code
model2 <- new_Japan_Data |>
model(TSLM(`Unemployment rate` ~ `Lending Rates` + Inflation + `RGDP Growth rate`) +
trend + variable + lag(`Unemployment rate`))

it keeps informing error
Error in UseMethod("model") :
no applicable method for 'model' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

> 

can someone help me with this

i run this successfully before and my new_Japan_data is normal

Comment: Make `new_Japan_Data` a tsibble.